# PHP inc/dec order of the sum of 2 numbers

Tags: php

how can i code the incrementing order of the sum of 2 numbers inside the function using while loop. if the sum is greater than 0 the order must be decrementing. if less than 0 it must be incrementing. if the sum for example is 5, it must be decremented until 0. but if it is -5 it must be incremented until 0. Thanks in Advance :)

```
    function inc($result){
    while ($_POST['result'] < 0){
echo $result;
$result++;
}

    function dec($result){
    while ($_POST['result'] > 0){
echo $result;
$result--;
}
```

Comment: it's sounds like infinite loop?

Comment: im sorry . i have'nt explain it well. but the result must be, if the sum for example is 5, it must be decremented until 0. but if it is -5 it must be incremented until 0.

Comment: Your trouble is you are not incrementing anything inside the function. In your function you are saying while $_POST['result'] is -5, well it will always be -5 and you will get an infinite loop unless you save to variable and increment/decrement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment because you are not incrementing or decrementing anything you are going to get infinite loops so you will need to assign $_POST['result'] to $result or another variable?

```
function inc($result) {
    while ($result < 0) {
        echo $result;
        $result++;
    }
}

function dec($result) {
    while ($result > 0) {
        echo $result;
        $result--;
    }
}
```

and insert $_POST['result'] as the argument for the function:

```
inc($_POST['result'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I did understand you correctly...
Do you mean something like this?

```
$result = $_POST['result'];
while ($result != 0) {
  echo $result;
  $result += ($result > 0 ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `range()` function to generate the array of numbers you want.
What you want to do with them is up to you:

```
$nums = range( min($_POST['result'], 0), max($_POST['result'], 0) );
```

It works in both cases, negative to zero and zero to positive.